# How do I rename packed images? (Script)

Tags: python

I've got a code that loads textures, and determines which is what with eNUM list of texture-type. Basically, I get the right textures connected to their right slots of the material (`e.g. 29318291083.TGA goes to Normal`). Now what I'm trying to do is rename them and export them out so the texture I just mentioned would come out as `29318291083_Normal.TGA`.

I assume Blender isn't able to rename external files so I added a line that packs each texture when it loads it, so I can rename it while packed, then export as a new .TGA.

Now I got the texture's packed but I don't seem to find a way to rename a packed texture.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Blender is able to do anything that you can do in python including renaming external files. I don't completely get what you are trying to do in detail, but you can rename textures in blender with

```
import bpy
bpy.data.textures['29318291083'].name = '29318291083_Normal'
```

In python you can rename a file with

```
import os
os.rename('a.txt', 'b.kml')
```

If your textures are stored similar to .obj and its .mtl (I didn't bother checking tbh) you can just use python to open the file, search for the right lines and rename them. As renaming files and editing text are very common methods, Stackoverflow provides you with lots of help.

Answer (score 0):

**Image type texture, is often named from the image filename**

For an image type texture the texture has an associated image. `bpy.types.Texture.image`

```
>>> D.textures['Texture'].type
'IMAGE'

>>> D.textures['Texture'].image
bpy.data.images['bar.tga']

>>> D.textures['Texture'].image.filepath
'/home/batfinger/foo/bar.tga'
```

which you can edit.  Avoid blender trying to reload from the new path by packing first. Recommend setting a relative filepath (relative to the  blend file path).

```
>>> name = "FooBar"
>>> D.textures['Texture'].image.filepath = f"//bar/{name}.tga"

>>> D.textures['Texture'].name = name
```

Now when unpacking will be given option to create a `Foobar.tga` image file in the `bar` folder of the folder hosting the blend.

Answer (score 0):

on blender 2.93.4
it only worked after I unpacked them all
renamed them inside blender script console:

```
bpy.data.images['SomeWeirdName'].name='MyCustomImgName1'
bpy.data.images['MyCustomImgName1'].filepath_raw='//textures/theNewFileName.jpg'
```

renamed them externally on the directory to match the `filepath_raw` in the blend file
packed them all again inside the blend file

to test, I trashed the textures folder
and just unpacked them all again

so, the internal blender name and the file name can be different, therefore the name can be more readable and short!